# Range/Loop through N variables in [modern] C++

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, c++14, c++17

What's a succinct way of ranging through N variables, of any type each, to perform an operation?

Let's say I have variables `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` and want to go through all of them performing some operation.

Comment: If you have 5 variables and you want to do the same thing with them, you probably need an array or a vector... (or another type of collection)

Comment: My question would be: Why do you want the same operation (actually, it can't be the same operation, it has to be a template or overload) on different types? This smells like bad design. Can you give a real world example, please?

Comment: @stefan the question is a mere exercise, answer was already provided.

Comment: @pepper_chico I see the question and answer. What I don't see is the problem behind it and the use case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Boost.Hana and generic lambdas:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/ext/std/tuple.hpp>

struct A {};
struct B {};
struct C {};
struct D {};
struct E {};

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    using boost::hana::for_each;

    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
    D d;
    E e;

    for_each(tie(a, b, c, d, e), [](auto &x) {
        cout << typeid(x).name() << endl;
    });
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ccb37ec1e453c9b4

Comment: Was gonna post this :)

Answer (score 4):

You may use: (C++11) (https://ideone.com/DDY4Si)

```
template <typename F, typename...Ts>
void apply(F f, Ts&&...args) {
    const int dummy[] = { (f(std::forward<Ts>(args)), 0)... };
    static_cast<void>(dummy); // avoid warning about unused variable.
}
```

With `F` a functor (or a generic lambda (C++14)).
You may call it like this in C++14:

```
apply([](const auto &x) { std::cout << typeid(x).name() << std::endl;}, a, b, c, d, e);
```

In C++17, with folding expression, it would be:

```
template <typename F, typename...Ts>
void apply(F f, Ts&&...args) {
    (static_cast<void>(f(std::forward<Ts>(args))), ... );
}
```

Comment: A C++11 functor may look like this: http://ideone.com/Hb4GBg Feel free to copy paste it in your answer.

Comment: @stefan: my linked sample also provide one :), but thanks anyway.

Comment: Ah, I guess I should have clicked that link ;-)

Comment: oneliner: `(void)(const int[]){ (f(std::forward<Ts>(args)), 0)... }`

Answer (score 0):

I love the [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) in C++11:

```
#include <iostream>  

struct S {int number;};

int main() {
    S s1{1}; 
    S s2{2};
    S s3{3};

    for (auto i : {s1, s2, s3}) {
        std::cout << i.number << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: nice but sadly, works solely for variables of same type.