# Iterate over a c++14 tuple with a lambda by using boost::mpl::for_each

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, boost-mpl

Is it possible to iterate over a tuple with a lambda using boost::mpl::for_each? MPL documentation creates a separate class away from the call size which iterates over types given to for_each, can a lambda be used instead? Or can the separate class be written to take as an argument a lambda that would be applied with all types given to for_each? Something like this, except that incrementer should take a lambda (in constructor?) which defines the operations to do and which could be written at the call site of for_each:

```
#include "boost/mpl/for_each.hpp"
#include "tuple"

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::mpl;

template<class Tuple_T>
struct incrementer
{
    incrementer(Tuple_T& given) : tuple(given){}
    template<class T> void operator()(const T&)
    {
        // how to write this in main() instead?
        // [&](?){? += 1}?
        get<T>(this->tuple) += 1;
    }
    Tuple_T& tuple;
};

int main(){
    tuple<int, float, double> t{1, 2, 3};
    for_each<int, double>(incrementer<decltype(t)>(t));
    assert(get<0>(t) == 2);
    assert(get<1>(t) == 2);
    assert(get<2>(t) == 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#include "tuple"` o.O (Standard) Library headers should be included with `<>`, i.e. `#include <tuple>`

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387354/template-tuple-calling-a-function-on-each-element should achieve what you want, though it doesn't use boost::mpl::for_each.

Comment: > I think stackoverflow.com/questions/16387354... <

That one uses indices/integers which won't work in this case.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a47a908c26467fd1 worked thanks, but c++1y is a bit too bleeding edge for me. Is there a c++11 way of doing something similar, perhaps with an external class taking a functor?

Comment: another c++14 one using tuples: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23235832. polymorphic lambdas seems the best tool you can get for the job.

Comment: @user3493721 c++1y refers to c++14! c++1z refers to candidate c++17.